# @supports (-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap) doesn't return true when Safari does support it

Tags: css, safari, flexbox, browser-feature-detection

I am using Safari 7.x.

I have the following feature query which always returns false.

```
@supports (-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap) {
}
```

What syntax do I need to use for this to return true when safari does understand `-webkit-flex-wrap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint, but Safari does not presently support the CSS `@supports` rule. [According to caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-featurequeries) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports), it is only supported in Firefox 22+, Chrome 28+, and Opera 12.1+. You still have to use JavaScript-based feature detection for Internet Explorer and Safari.

Here is an example feature-detection script that adds a `supports-webkit-flex-wrap` to the root element in the DOM.

```
if ('webkitFlexWrap' in document.documentElement.style) {
    document.documentElement.classList.add('supports-webkit-flex-wrap');
}
```

Then you can apply styles using that class name.

```
.supports-webkit-flex-wrap {
}
```

Comment: Sweet, i'm going to go try that.  Thanks for your time!  Will accept as soon as i can..

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Do you happen to know if it's possible to combine @supports() or the classname in one declaration?

Comment: @rix I can't think of any way to combine them, no. Sorry.